# SSRS - Shrink report width when hiding columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Using SSRS 2013. I am able to hide columns with boolean values, but the report (body) width does not shrink when columns are hidden. Thus, there is excess blank/white space to the right of the report. Is it possible to eliminate this excess space? If yes, kindly will you please advise how?

Comment: Note: I am dealing with columns that are contained within a tablix. Sorry for omitting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The report body width - as with any column width and unlike heights - is a set value that cannot be changed on execution.  You need to either put up with the white space, format your presentation layer to not be affected by the appearance of the white space or redesign your report so the objective of hiding the columns can be achieved in a different way.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.  Can you make any recommendations on how to redesign the report to solve this problem?

Comment: Not without seeing your data, your requirements and reporting environment within which the report sits.  At that point however I'd probably start charging you consultancy fees...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same limitation of SSRS. I was able to achieve what *I believe* you are trying to get (consistent report and report col width when certain columns are hidden due to parameter vals, etc.)- by simply having 2, separately formatted report tablix/tables in the report and hiding/showing based on a parameter (or some SSRS-expressible logic):

1 for the condition when all columns are present; 1 for the condition when some columns are omitted- both of them formatted to utilize all available screen real estate to minimize white space and make things look "clean".

Instead of hiding column(s) when my hidden condition is true- I simply show the 2nd tablix and hide the 1st. And when the filter changes to show all columns, I do the reverse (hide the 2nd tablix and make the 1st visible again).

Not sure if that helps, but I figured I should share if it might aid anybody else facing this issue.

PS: Your tablix Hidden expressions will look something like this:

```
[the full column tablix].Hidden
=iif(Parameters!parmOmitSomeCols.Value = true, false, true)

[the tablix with some columns omitted].Hidden
=iif(Parameters!parmOmitSomeCols.Value = false, true, false)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. There are multiple combinations of columns that can be shown or excluded. From what I think you are telling me, I would need to build a tablix for each combination and then use the logic that you provided to effectively determine which tablix to use (i.e., a case/switch)? Or, are you saying that I can have 1 tablix with all columns displayed and then another tablix that handles 1 + n combination of hidden columns?

Comment: Ahh. I see. Yes, I am saying the former (separate tablix for each combo- in my case there was only 2 combos so it was the best way to go). In your situation, dynamically re-sizable columns would easily solve the problem. Unfortunately, from my research it seems that this feature has been asked for since SSRS 2005.. to no avail. :/